# Show that the set of solutions of $f(x)=0$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem.**
>
> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that the exist no $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the simultaneous equality $f'(x)=f(x)=0$ holds. Show that, the set of solutions of the equation $f(x)=0$ is finite.

I thought to apply the method of contradiction here, i.e., I assume that the  the set of solutions of the equation $f(x)=0$ is infinite but I can't find any such $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the simultaneous equality $f'(x)=f(x)=0$ holds.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Given an infinite set in $[0,1]$, what can you do with it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Depends on the problem.

Comment: So, you don't feel like contributing to your solution? Why is it $[0,1]$, and not $(0,1)$ or $\mathbb R$ or $[0,1)$? Do you think it is true if you replace $[0,1]$ with any of those other sets?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: If I knew, then probably I would have found out the solution myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea:** The key idea is to use [Bolzano—Weierstrass's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to find a sequence of zeroes of $f$ that converges: we can do it since the set $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded.

By contrapositive, suppose the set $S$ of zeroes of $f$ is infinite. Since $S\subseteq [0,1]$ is bounded and infinite, there exists a convergent sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $S$. Let $s\in[0,1]$ be its limit, and note that $s\in[0,1]$ (since $[0,1]$ is closed).

We want to show that $f^\prime(s)=f(s)=0$. The ingredients will be:

- $f$ is continuous.
- $f$ is differentiable, so in particular for any $t\in[0,1]$, we have $f^\prime(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(t_n)-f(t)}{t_n -t}$ for every sequence $(t_n)_n\in[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $t$ (such that $t_n\neq t$ for all $n$).

---

**More detail:**

- Then $0=f(s_n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} f(s)$ by continuity, so $f(s)=0$.
- Note that we can assume that the $s_n$'s are distinct (since $S$ is infinite). We will therefore assume, without loss of generality, that the sequence $(s_n)_n$ satisfies $s_n\neq s$ for all $n$. Then we have $$f^\prime(s) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(s_n)-f(s)}{s_n-s} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{0-0}{s_n-s} = 0.$$