# Set of solutions of $f(x)=0$ using intermediate value theorem

Tags: continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I'm given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ continuous, takes a non-negative value somewhere  in $[0,1)$ and is strictly negative at $1$, i.e. $f(1)<0$. By IVT we know the solution set of $f(x)=0$ is non-empty. My question is, can we show it is compact? I saw examples such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663104/show-that-the-set-of-solutions-of-fx-0-is-finite) which use differentiability (which I don't have) but also requires finiteness of the solution set (which I don't need).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes since the zero set is closed and clearly bounded.

Comment: Important properties of continuity to remember to exploit:  Inverse images preserve open/closed sets,   images of connected sets are connected,  and as long as your range is $T_2$ (Like any metric space),  images of compact sets are compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. We see that $\{x \in [0, 1] | f(x) = 0\}$ is bounded. It is also closed, since it can be written as $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ is closed. A closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Conversely, any compact set $C \subseteq [0, 1]$ is a solution set to $f(x) = 0$ for some continuous $f$. In this case, define $f(x) = \min\limits_{c \in C} |c - x|$ if $C$ is non-empty, $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. Then $f$ is continuous and $f(x) = 0$ iff $x \in C$.